# Passing variable names to functions

Tags: function, lua

I have an application and some code that works but I want to make it a callable function such as :-

`tankFunction("tank1")` so that the below function (which works) would be able to work for any tank as per the entered parameter `"tank1"` or `"tank2"` or `"tank3"` and so on..

So basically each variable contained in the existing function would represent the enter parameter:

```
tank1CoolManCtrlOn = reg.tank1CoolManCtrlOn
```

Currently, the two above variables are coded just for `"tank1"`, if `"tank2"` were passed into `tankfucntion` such as `tankfunction("tank2")` then the variables would need to be:

```
tank2CoolManCtrlOn = reg.tank2CoolManCtrlOn
```

So the variables would be `####CoolManCtrlon = reg.####CoolManCtrlOn` where the `####` is where the parameter needs to be entered.

Once these variables are created they then need to be passed to the `tank()` function and the returned values need to be then set to the output registers.

```
function tank1Function()  
--Tank1 - Start
--This is the Control Function Block Call for - Tank1

--Below is where each variable is set for the function block call.
tank1CoolManCtrlOn = reg.tank1CoolManCtrlOn
tank1CoolManCtrlOff = reg.tank1CoolManCtrlOff
tank1HeatManCtrlOn = reg.tank1HeatManCtrlOn
tank1HeatManCtrlOff = reg.tank1HeatManCtrlOff
tank1PV = reg.tank1PV
tank1SV = reg.tank1SV
tank1Debounce = reg.tank1Debounce
tank1Hysteresis = reg.tank1Hysteresis
tank1LowAlm = reg.tank1LowAlm
tank1HighAlm = reg.tank1HighAlm
tank1CoolManIND = reg.tank1CoolManIND
tank1HeatManIND = reg.tank1HeatManIND
tank1Mode = reg.tank1Mode
tank1CTRLType = reg.tank1CTRLType

--This is the function block call for Tank1 where each parameter is set.
 tank1CoolManIND1, tank1HeatManIND1, tank1CoolManCtrlOn1,
 tank1CoolManCtrlOff1, tank1HeatManCtrlOn1, tank1HeatManCtrlOff1  = 
 tank(tank1CoolManCtrlOn, tank1CoolManCtrlOff, tank1HeatManCtrlOn, 
 tank1HeatManCtrlOff, tank1PV, tank1SV, tank1Debounce, tank1Hysteresis, 
 tank1LowAlm, tank1HighAlm, tank1CoolManIND, tank1HeatManIND, tank1Mode, 
 tank1CTRLType) 

 --This is where the results of the function block set the required  
 --Variables.
 reg.tank1CoolManIND = tank1CoolManIND1
 reg.tank1HeatManIND = tank1HeatManIND1
 reg.tank1CoolManCtrlOn = tank1CoolManCtrlOn1 
 reg.tank1CoolManCtrlOff =  tank1CoolManCtrlOff1
 reg.tank1HeatManCtrlOn =  tank1HeatManCtrlOn1
 reg.tank1HeatManCtrlOff = tank1HeatManCtrlOff1
--Tank1 - End  

 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable names have a lot of repetition, which means you could easily represent your tanks in nested tables.

```
local tanks = {{}, {}, {}}
local reg = {tanks = {{}, {}, {}}}

local function tank(t)
  return {
    -- Calculate fields from t.
  }
end

local function tankFunction(i)
  tanks[i] = reg.tanks[i]
  reg.tanks[i] = tank(tanks[i])
end

tankFunction(1)
```

The tank tables would have keys such as `PV`, `SV`, and `Debounce`.